# Navigation Menu not working - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

We are using a wordpress site (v 4.5.1) with the Impreza theme 1.10.4. After I upgraded Wordpress it seems like the navigation menu disappeared.

The site is located here: https://electratherm.com/

I got the top level (parent) navigation to appear by adding this css code:

```
.w-nav-list.level_1 {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Now I have the problem that my sub-level (child) menus are not appearing. I don't know if this has to do with the latest Wordpress upgrade but I really need those submenus to work.

Just for reference there are sub-menus under just about everything except Home and Contact Us.

Comment: thre register_nav_menus() in fucntions.php has the menus listed right?

Answer (score 0):

Console shows a JavaScript error related to: `.w-nav-item a[href*=#]`

This is very likely preventing the rest of the JavaScript from firing that controls the menu items. Adding `display:` `block` overriding `none` on top level menu rollover.

Do you recognize that bit from anywhere in the theme JS files? It would be easiest to do a "Find In Files" type search of all theme files to locate this problem code and fix.